# phpunit test methods that take data from db

Tags: mysql, sql, testing, phpunit, tdd

in my app I have a special class to work with DB. 
And I have methods that SELECT data from BD and return the result as an array. But when I try to cover this methods with PHPUnit, I always have NULL in return.

here is my piece of code

```
public function getData($id) {
    $selectQuery = $dataBase->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id');
    $selectQery->bindInt(':id', $id);
    $selectQuery->execute();

    $result = $selectQuery->toArray();

    return $result;
}
```

before getting result I can see with debuger that SQL query is ok, ID is binded and the method has to return an array. and it returns if to run the method in my app. But the test gives NULL result.

How can I cover this method with tests and make sure that it returns a correct array of data?